# Changing content inside an element?

Tags: javascript, dom

**I'm attempting to use multiple movies inside the same container and make them play when different buttons are clicked.**

One is for my landing page, one is for the about us...etc.

I am attempting to use JavaScript to write a function to call the movies interdependently. I would like to press on navigation button's then different things pop up. JavaScript is what I assume I should use but I'm an a**hole so I figured I'd ask you good people. I am studying the DOM but really have no practice in using it. I have made an Image map which is a (swf.) which I'd like to load when people click about us, a Quick Time movie for the landing page, also a file I'm working on to run and loop after the landing page movie runs or if someone clicks on home. As I said I want them all to appear in the same container when some one clicks on the navigation buttons.

I know, that's it...I'm stuck, I have been confused for a few days reading different blogs, w3schools, StackOverflow, QuirksMode...still no idea how to approach it appropriately.

I figured I'd first create a separate JavaScript file. **Duh**

OK I should be more *specific*.
`WHERE DO THE OBJECTS GO? IN THE HTML OR JAVASCRIPT?
HOW DO I REFERENCE THEM? OnClick, getElementById()...both????`

I understand the basic principles so I have confidence if you gave me a nudge I could write the code correctly so please don't smack the programming out of me.

`What I do know is they all have to be the same size, how to airbrush and screenprint...that doesn't help though, and how to go to w3schools and read.`

Comment: So those "videos" aren't all in the same format? A SWF and then a MOV file?

Comment: No but I could go in and change them all to the same format...It would just be opportune to use the flash for the image map because I spent a bunch of hours in Flash creating it. I could go into after effects and remake the quicktime movies as something else??? May I ask the purpose??? I'm not sure what errors I'm giving myself...

Comment: When you post comment on someone else comment, use `@` to notify that person otherwise he won't see what you wrote. For example @DanMan will now notify him of this comment.

Comment: No but I could go in and change them all to the same format...It would just be opportune to use the flash for the image map because I spent a bunch of hours in Flash creating it. I could go into after effects and remake the quicktime movies as something else??? May I ask the purpose??? I'm not sure what errors I'm giving myself...@DanMan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good book for you might be [PPK on JavaScript](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/0321423305).  A good reference is [Javascript: The Definitive Guide, 5th Edn](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/0596101996)  (nb: [6th Edn](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9781449393854) due by March!)

Here's how it should work for you:

a) you put all of your resources into an HTML file - swf's, pictures, movies, the lot.  Put all the swappable things inside their own `<div id="thingId" />` elements inside a big `<div id="centrestage"/>` element.  It will seem a big mess of things for now, but don't panic. For the element that you want to show 'first' when the page loads, make it a `<div id="thingId" class="onstage" />`

... this gets all your resources into the HTML file.

b) supposing all your buttons are img's, you'll put `<img id="button1" />`, for button2, button3, etc.

b) you attach a stylesheet to your HTML with a rule as follows:

```
  div.centrestage div { display: none; }
  div.centrestage div.onstage { display: block; }
```

... this hides the resources you don't want displayed for now

c) you attach a JavaScript to your HTML that does the following things:

```
  window.onLoad = function(e) {

     var centrestage = document.getElementById('centrestage');
     var r1 = document.getElementById('resource1');
     var r2 = document.getElementById('resource2');

     var currentResource = r1;

     var b1 = document.getElementById('button1');
     button1.onClick = function(e) {
         currentResource.className = '';
         r1.className = 'onstage';
         currentResource = r1;
     }

     var b2 = document.getElementById('button2');
     button1.onClick = function(e) {
         currentResource.className = '';
         r2.className = 'onstage';
         currentResource = r2;
     }

  }
```

... notice that this script doesn't DO anything yet ... it just attaches some functions to some onClick events, of some objects that you've picekd out of the DOM tree by name.  The functions basically turn on/off the 'onstage' class attribute for the `DIV`'s, and the stylesheet does the rest.

As you probably get the gist of ... once the browser has read your HTML, you've got a DOM object model 'in memory'.  Once this model finishes loading, the browser hunts for any scripts which registered themselves in the onLoad event, and executes them.  This way of doing things helps to separate all the *structure* (HTML/DOM) from the *look* (CSS) from the *behaviour* (JavaScript hanging off DOM events).

Comment: THANK YOU GREATLY...as with anything new, code is unfamiliar at first but the more I read the more approachable it becomes. Thank you for the resources as well. @David Bullock

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quite simple example I wrote. When clicking on the link it will change the text in the div with id 'panel'.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function changeContent()
            {
                var element = document.getElementById('panel');
                element.innerHTML = 'hello';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="changeContent()">Click me</a>
        <div id="panel">after the click this will show hello</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The key is the `element.innerHTML`. In this case I just added a text, but of course you can add whatever HTML you need, for example your embed code of the SWF files.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help me out. Robe I'm going to go over this now I just wanted to let you know I thank you